# Gradle build can not resolve all Path_provider dependencies

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I was able to add **path_provider** library to **my pubspec.yaml** file and I used its functionalities in my code.
    When I tried to flutter run, I got an gradle build error.

---

**This is the error message:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider:lintClassPath'.
> Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.3.0).
  Searched in the following locations:                                  
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.3.0/intellij-core-26.3.0.jar
> Could not find kotlin-compiler.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.3.0).
  Searched in the following locations:                                  
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/26.3.0/kotlin-compiler-26.3.0.jar
> Could not find uast.jar (com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.3.0).
  Searched in the following locations:                                  
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/26.3.0/uast-26.3.0.jar
```

**My android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
  }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**What I tried:**

- Tried downgrading and upgrading gradle plugin.
- Tried adding maven repository

  buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
        jcenter()
    }

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by doing the following :

1. Upgrading Gradle to version 5.4.1 .
2. Upgrading Gradle plugin version to 3.5.0 .
3. Run the command `./gradlew dependencies` in project's android 
   directory which downloaded missing path_provider dependencies.
4. Run `flutter clean` then `flutter run`.